# Pairing with "non-ios" device programmatically

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

A further question about Bluetooth and iPhone.

Is it possible to discover nearby "non-ios" devices via bluetooth programmatically? The device uses the Hands-free-Profile. When I go like "General > Bluetooth > On" it works fine and I can pair with it. And thats exactly what I want to do but in my own App. I know the official SDK doesn`t support it. So my questions are:

1. When I`m member of the "Made for iPod"-Program, will I have access to the Hands-free-Profile API?
   Important: The device already exists and I have no influence on it. So no possibility to implement
             a special ship or so.
2. Another opportunity I found is the Private Framework BluetoothManager.h. Is it possible to
   discover/pair the device with an iPhone?

In one sentence: I want to build an app that exactly does what the Bluetooth-function in the iPhone settings does. Possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to build an app that exactly does what the Bluetooth-function in the iPhone settings does. Possible?

No, it is not possible with official APIs, even if you are a part of the Made for iPhone program.

Comment: Ok thx. And unofficial? What about the Private API I mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is that specific private API, but yes, it should be possible with some private API. Reverse-engineer how Apple does it if you want to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

> In one sentence: I want to build an app that exactly does what the Bluetooth-function in the iPhone settings does. Possible?

A preliminary search didn't find the official rule about it, but Apple specifically forbids apps that duplicate the functionality of their built-ins.  So, no, your app will almost certainly not get approved.

And I'm pretty sure the T&C forbid interaction with non-Apple-approved devices, but I'm not sure whether they strictly apply that to bluetooth things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I know they changed the rules so it's possible to duplicate features: http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/iphone/articles/90193.aspx

Comment: Good to know, they so rarely reverse themselves.  Though I think to get through on that, you still need to add some nontrivial feature that they don't have.

Comment: The T&C does not forbid interaction with non-Apple-approved devices, just look at the iCade, which is not Made for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , using the bluetooth private APIs. You can get a list of remote devices, each a BluetoothDevice object, and use the afferent methods to pair or connect.